# Terminating a detached thread (from in it) in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, terminate

The thing is, I have detached threads created on my server which works in a thread-per-client way, so the function which accepts a client, creates another listener function (as a thread, and detaches it) waiting for another client to join.

Like the following in pseudo code:

```
Listen to client...
Accept Client Connection...
If client connection is Valid then
Create and detach a thread of the exact same function.
Else
Keep on listening...
```

I detach the threads only because afterwards, the thread who created a certain thread is handling a client, if that client leaves all clients that logged in after that client would be forced to log out (because there's a chain of threads):

```
//-> means creating a thread
Listening thread... Handling Client 1 -> Listening... Handling 2 -> Listening... Handling 3
```

and so on. So when client 1's thread will terminate, all of the others would do so.

That is why I cannot give up on detach (unless I'd create the threads in the `main()`, obviously, but that's not the architecture of the program).

Now, the problem occurs when someone exits without informing a thing, so the thread won't peacefully end. The only time I notice the fact that a client is not online is when `recv()` or `send()` are returning a negative value. When I notice that, I have to terminate the thread.

I tried doing so by using `std::terminate()` but I get an error window saying `r6010 - abort() has been called.`

How do I terminate that thread without all of the server crashing?

Would I be forced to change the architecture ?

Comment: Have a variable 'state' indicating the detached thread to stop.You can not terminate a detached thread (besides quitting the whole process)

Comment: Have you tried just returning from the function?

Comment: @NathanOliver, I have a function responsible of receiving, and a function responsible of sending. If I return, I am still in the same thread, just as if I were ignoring the call for the functions

Comment: @DieterLücking So it is not possible? I did suspect so. Is there a real reason why it is not possible?

Comment: @Dieter Lücking With pthreads at least couldn't you call `phtread_exit` to end a detached thread?

Answer (score 1):

The way to end a thread is to return from its thread procedure.

If you want the ending decision to be made from deep inside processing code, then throw an exception that is caught by the thread procedure.  This has several huge benefits over `pthread_exit`:

- Stack unwinding occurs, so dynamic allocations used by your processing code won't be leaked (if properly held in smart pointers), as well as any other cleanup performed in destructors (flushing file buffers, etc).
- In the future if you want to add retry logic or anything like that, you can catch the exception.  Conversely a call to `pthread_exit` is like a call to `std::terminate` or `std::exit` -- the current context ends unconditionally (although a handler can be installed via `set_terminate`, that handler cannot cancel the exit).  Reusable code should *never* force an application-level exit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put test a variable in your client comms loop that signals a thread when to return:

```
class ClientComms
{
    // set to true when you want the thread to stop
    std::atomic_bool done;

public:
    ClientComms(): done(false) {}

    void operator()()
    {
        while(!done)
        {
             // communicate with client
        }
    }
};
```